# Using OSM maps in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, render, openstreetmap

I've downloaded OSM map from geofabrik.de and i want it to display in my C# WPF application. Is there any example of how to render and display OSM local stored maps(osm.pbf map loaded from geofabrik) in c# application?

Comment: we use Telerik WPF Map, using the OpenStreetMapProvider

Comment: @Nobody - ok, thx. Is it free liscence?

Comment: comercial license, its not free